# How do I get filenames and line numbers in c# stack traces running in edge.js on OSX

Tags: c#, node.js, macos, mono, edge.js

This is specifically about getting line numbers in stack traces when running c# under edge.js.

Given this C# source file (test.cs)

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace test {
    public class Startup {
        public async Task<object> Invoke(dynamic input) {
            try {
                throw new Exception("some error");
            } catch(Exception e) {
                Console.WriteLine(e);
            }
            return null;
       }
    }
}
```

I'm building a .dll (and .dll.mdb) with the command:

```
mcs -debug -target:library -out:test.dll test.cs
```

And running with this edge.js script:

```
var edge = require('edge');

var myfunc = edge.func({
    assemblyFile: __dirname + '/test.dll'
});

myfunc(true, function(err, result) { });
```

The stack trace in the output has no filename or line numbers:

```
System.Exception: some error
  at test.Startup+<Invoke>c__async0.MoveNext () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

Is there a way to get filenames and line numbers in the stack trace instead of <filename unknown>:0 ?

From the command line, mono must be run using the --debug argument in order to get line numbers.  If that's the case here, then this question may boil down to "How do i pass arguments to CLR from edge.js?"

Versions: node.js:v0.10.39, mcs/mono:4.0.4.0, edge.js:4.0.0

[Edit]
I found you can get command line arguments into mono from edge by setting the environment variable MONO_ENV_OPTIONS.  Unfortunately this doesn't work with --debug.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I include line numbers in a stack trace without a pdb?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1328836/how-can-i-include-line-numbers-in-a-stack-trace-without-a-pdb)

Comment: Not a duplicate.  This is specifically about c# code running under edge.js.

Comment: Debugging information is in the .mdb file generated by mcs.  When running from the command line, filenames and line numbers are present.  This is *specifically* about running under edge.js.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After researching this, seems like edge does not provide a way to activate debugging in the embedded mono, you need to modify and build edge yourself to accomplish it. It is a quick process, though, once you figure it out:

**1.** Install edge for your project normally with:

```
npm install edge
```

I did follow the steps for [building on OSX](https://github.com/tjanczuk/edge#building-on-osx), but it's not necessary.

**2.** Change `node_modules/edge/src/mono/monoembedding.cpp` to include `mono-debug.h` and call `mono_debug_init` within `MonoEmbedding::Initialize`. The file should look something like this:

```
#include <dlfcn.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <libgen.h>
#include "edge.h"

#include "mono/metadata/mono-debug.h" //This is new
#include "mono/metadata/assembly.h"
#include "mono/metadata/mono-config.h"
#include "mono/jit/jit.h"


MonoAssembly* MonoEmbedding::assembly = NULL;

void MonoEmbedding::Initialize()
{
    ...

    //This is new. Must be called before 'mono_jit_init'
    mono_debug_init(MONO_DEBUG_FORMAT_MONO);
    mono_config_parse (NULL);
    mono_jit_init (fullPath);
    ...
}
```

**3.** From `node_modules/edge/`, build edge using:

```
node-gyp configure build
```

You might get an error similar to:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'nan'
```

In that case run `npm install --save nan`, that should fix it.

**4.** Run your test again. Output is now:

```
System.Exception: some error   
    at test.Startup+<Invoke>c__async0.MoveNext () 
   [0x00019] in /Developer/tests/so/test.cs:8
```